# SQL Server table with 4,000,000 rows is 40GB

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-size

I have been trying to figure out why our production database has grown so much recently and have found the cause to be an audit table. We are going to archive the table to fix the problem but I just wanted to check if the size of the table looked normal for a large SQL server table like this.
It has 4,000,000 rows with the following structure...

```
Name                    Type        Nullable
AuditLogId              bigint      no
UserName                nvarchar    no
TimeOfChange            datetime    no
ObjectName              nvarchar    no
ChangeName              nvarchar    no
RecordId                int         yes
OriginalValues          nvarchar    yes
ResultingValues         nvarchar    no
```

With a primary key on the AuditLogId

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditLog] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_AuditLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AuditLogId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

There is also a foreign key to the record that was updated on RecordId.
The nvarchar fields seem to have up to 12,0000 characters with an average of around 8000 characters.
The table is currently 40GB in size, does that seem right? I can provide more information on the table if that question can’t be answered with what I have posted above.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked index fragmentation? Does this table have lots of inserts and deletes? If you are not maintaining the indexes and lots of data gets inserted and later deleted, the index structure can become rather lopsided. Rebuilding the indexes as a whole to properly distribute the data could be helpful. I don't see any index information in your post so I didn't post this as an answer in case this is not your problem.

Comment: Which nvarchar field has 8000 characters? And why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have 4,000,000 rows and one of the columns averages 8,000 characters (16,000 bytes, I assume).

```
SELECT CONVERT(bigint,4000000) * /* b */ 16000 / /*kb*/ 1024 / /*mb*/ 1024;
------
61,035
```

If your stats are accurate, I'd expect this table to be 61 GB. (I wonder if you mean 8,000 bytes, not 8,000 characters, in which case I'd expect > 30 GB.)

Other factors include:

- data in other columns I didn't account for in the above calculation
- additional indexes
- fill factor > 0 and < 100
- fragmentation and space still occupied by deleted rows or page splits

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server nvarchar columns are [two bytes per character](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-nvarchar/) so if you have 12k characters then yes you could easily have a very large table. If the column doesn't store unicode data then it could be converted to varchar which would free up some storage.